# How can I specify Hadoop XML configuration variables via the Hadoop shell scripts?

Tags: hadoop, environment-variables, hdfs

I'm writing code to create a temporary Hadoop cluster. Unlike most Hadoop clusters, I need the location for logs, HDFS files, etc, to be in a specific temporary network location that is different each time the cluster is started. This network directory will be *generated at runtime*; I do not know the directory name at the time I'm checking in the shell scripts like `hadoop-env.sh` and the XML files like `core-default.xml`.

- At **checkin time**: I can modify the shell scripts like `hadoop-env.sh` and the XML files like `core-default.xml`.
- At **run time**: I generate the temporary directory that I want to use for my data storage.

I can instruct most of Hadoop to use this temporary directory by specifying environment variables like `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` and `HADOOP_PID_DIR`, and if necessary I can modify the shell scripts to read those environment variables.

However, HDFS determines its local directory to store the filesystem via two properties that are defined in XML files, not environment variables or shell scripts: `hadoop.tmp.dir` in [core-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in [hdfs-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml).

**Is there any way to edit these XML files to determine the value of `hadoop.tmp.dir` at runtime?** Or, alternatively, **is there any way to use environment variables to override the XML-configured value of `hadoop.tmp.dir`?**

Comment: Very interesting question! Out of curiosity and maybe future reference, why do you need such functionality?

Comment: @vefthym: It's for automated testing of how my software integrates with Hadoop. The machine on which the test will be running doesn't normally have Hadoop running on it, and must not have Hadoop running on it afterwards; but I have free rein for the duration of the test to run whatever processes I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had a similar requirement earlier. Configuring dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir as part of HADOOP_OPTS worked well for us. For e.g.

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Ddfs.name.dir=$NAMENODE_DATA -Ddfs.data.dir=$DFS_DATA"
```

This method can be used to configure other configurations also, like namenode url.

Comment: A couple of notes for future visitors: * The property names in Hadoop 1.x are "dfs.name.dir" etc, but in Hadoop 2.x are "dfs.namenode.name.dir" etc. * If you specify "-Ddfs.namenode.name.dir=", you need to give the path prefixed by "file://". * It worked out simpler for me to just specify "-Dhadoop.tmp.dir=". * This needs to be defined on the worker nodes, so either in your hadoop-env.sh or similar scripts, or in an environment variable forwarded to the workers.